# How to find the equivalent/corresponding translation of 64bit assembly code from its 32bit counterpart?

Tags: assembly

if I know what something looks like in the 32bit version of a compiled program (looking at the assembly code), how can I find the 64bit instruction where the same stuff is being carried out in a 64bit version of the program (which besides being 64bit is otherwise identical, no added features)

people have suggested I somehow learn the manuals located below for an answer: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html

but the problem is I don't have a clue what they are hinting at, is there an example/sample someone can show me of how this would look?

basically - can I take a set of lines from the 32bit version of a program and 'translate' them into 64bit code manually so that I can find the corresponding section in the 64bit version?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you "translated" them, it's unlikely you'd find a one-to-one correspondence. x64 has additional registers, additional addressing schemes, different structure and data sizes and alignment requirements which impose restrictions. Add to that optimizations performed by a compiler and it's highly unlikely you'd be able to do what you suggest.

You can get hints by locating nearby `call` instructions and identifying them by their targets, or unique (or rare) constants.

With all that said, what exactly are you trying to achieve and what is the *problem* you are trying to solve?